# Getting CORS policy error while request withCredentials: true in Spring REST

Tags: axios, vuejs3, spring-rest

My RestController , added @CrossOrigin its allows "/signup" but requesting '/login' withCredentials: true from front end app getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

My RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addNewUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) throws DataAlreadyPresent {
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(userService.addUser(user),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public JwtResponse authenticateAndGetToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getEmail(), authRequest.getPassword()));
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(authRequest.getEmail());
            return JwtResponse.builder()
                    .accessToken(jwtService.generateToken(authRequest.getEmail()))
                    .token(refreshToken.getToken()).build();
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("invalid user request !");
        }
    }
```

my Request from Login.vue method

```
async login(){
      await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',this.authData,{
        withCredentials: true
      })
          .then(res =>{
            console.log(res.data);
          });
    }
```

Getting CORS policy error, while request withCredentials: true in Spring REST

How to allow request from my front end app?

Answer (score 0):

Got Fixed ,
added
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080", allowCredentials = "true")`

in my controller